# Unable to update AWS S3 CORS POLICY

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors

I needed to change my AWS S3 bucket CORS policy to enable the upload of files for my ReactJS to AWS S3, but I keep getting this API response:

> Expected params.CORSConfiguration.CORSRules to be an Array.

I am at a loss right now. Can anyone help?

[image: Error message]

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. The example AWS provides is not working:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ManageCorsUsing.html

`
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "http://www.example.com"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [
            "x-amz-server-side-encryption",
            "x-amz-request-id",
            "x-amz-id-2"
        ],
        "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
    }
]
`

Answer (score 43):

I'm not sure if this helps. I ran into this same problem recently and it seems like AWS made some changes with how we define our CORS configurations. For example, if you want to allow certain Methods on your S3 bucket in the past you have to do something like this on the editor:

```
<CORSConfiguration>
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
```

The config below is equivalent to the one on the top but takes the form of an array.

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "HEAD",
            "DELETE"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [],
        "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
    }
]
```

Let me know if this helps. Thank you!

Comment: Useful answer. Would be even more helpful if you attach a link explaining "it seems like AWS made some changes"

Comment: it does not work. I get Unknown Error
An unexpected error occurred.
API response
Policies must be valid JSON and the first byte must be '{'

Comment: It worked in place of XML styled version which was mentioned by others

Answer (score 5):

We encountered the same error. We needed two fixes. (Not sure if this is helpful in your case):

1. Pay attention to the type of quotes used: "" vs  “”. Use the former
2. Make sure you do not have a trailing comma on the second to last line, following the bracket.

Answer (score 3):

```
[
{
    "AllowedHeaders": [
        "*"
    ],
    "AllowedMethods": [
        "POST",
        "PUT",
        "GET",
        "HEAD",
        "DELETE"
    ],
    "AllowedOrigins": [
        "*"
    ],
    "ExposeHeaders": [
        "x-amz-server-side-encryption",
        "x-amz-request-id",
        "x-amz-id-2",
        "ETag"
    ],
    "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
}
```

]

Comment: Quick question: I am getting 403 forbidden error! any idea why is it happening?

Answer (score 2):

To configure CORS for your static website the CORS object has to be in JSON format [see aws docs cors configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html#how-do-i-enable-cors). To specify the actions allowed on that bucket you want to enable CORS on, you must define a set of CORS Rules. The CORS Rules is an array that holds a set of objects where each object corresponds to a particular rule. To learn more about how to define CORS Rules [see aws cors rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_CORSRule.html). The error you are receiving is due the fact that your CORS Rule is in improper format. If you follow the above example by @FaitAccompli the error should be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

```
[{
    "AllowedHeaders": [
        "*"
    ],
    "AllowedMethods": [
        "GET",
        "PUT",
        "POST",
        "HEAD",
        "DELETE"
    ],
    "AllowedOrigins": [
        "*"
    ],
    "ExposeHeaders": [],
    "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
}]
```

This worked for me. This need to be added on AWS S3 "Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS)" section.

Hoe this helps.

Answer (score 0):

use JSON validator tool [https://jsonlint.com/](https://jsonlint.com)

you might miss a small mistake in your JSON which will lead to this kind of error, unfortunately, AWS error messages can be rather vague at times, making it difficult to pinpoint exactly where the problem lies